# Windows Server: file system limitation

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, filesystems, ntfs, copy

We are developing an app for tablet which uploads and saves photos taken by the user. The problem we are suddenly meeting is that photos are not saved anymore in our directory in our Windows server 2008 r2 standard, but they remain in TEMP directory: we get this error:

> 0x80070299 File system limitation. Not possible to save file in directory.

but the disk is very very little defragmented (8%); we have also run chkdsk but no error is shown. Our hard disk is NTFS.
Do you know how we can discover the problem?
Moreover in that directory it seems to be possible to create files, but not to copy them in it.

Comment: Are you trying to upload large (>30GB) files and have NTFS compression enabled?

Comment: In addition to Sven's question, how long is the path ([MAX_PATH, 260 characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)), how many files are in your directory, and how large is it?

Comment: No, the files we are trying to copy have a size of some MBs while NTFS compression is disabled for that directory and path should be ok, they have a path of about 100 chars...it has always worked fine until this morning

Comment: in that directory there are more than 2.000.000 files so  guess that is the cause...we should split into subdirectories

Comment: Is 8dot3name creation disabled? Please verufy

Comment: Command is `fsutil 8dot3name query D:`